# Solve Generalized Eigenvalue Problem in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I am looking to solve a problem of the type:  `Aw = xBw` where `x` is a scalar (eigenvalue), `w` is an eigenvector, and `A` and `B` are symmetric, square numpy matrices of equal dimension.  I should be able to find `d` x/w pairs if `A` and `B` are `d x d`.  How would I solve this in numpy?  I was looking in the Scipy docs and not finding anything like what I wanted.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672408/generalized-eigenvectors-in-matlab

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do, but in python.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For real symmetric or complex Hermitian dense matrices, you can use [`scipy.linalg.eigh()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html) to solve a generalized eigenvalue problem. To avoid extracting all the eigenvalues you can specify only the desired ones by using `subset_by_index`:

```
from scipy.linalg import eigh

eigvals, eigvecs = eigh(A, B, eigvals_only=False, subset_by_index=[0, 1, 2])
```

One could use `eigvals_only=True` to obtain only the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up!  That example in the docs for this function was pretty unclear at first glance.

Comment: This is reassuring for my purposes, @Saullo, but I'm having problems.  By my reckoning, eigh is a specialisation of eig.  However, if I use eigh and eig with the same inputs I get *completely* different answers.  Is there an additional distinction?

Comment: @MikeSadler, are you using symmetric matrices as input?

Comment: @SaulloG.P.Castro, I am - I was checking them in my test case that they were both symmetric and positive definite.  I've side-stepped the problem now, but could it be that eig and eigh don necessarily return the results in the same order?

Comment: @MikeSadler Indeed. According to the documentation, `numpy.linalg.eigh` returns "the eigenvalues in ascending order, each repeated according to its multiplicity." There is no predefined eigenvalue order with `numpy.linalg.eig`

Answer (score 13):

Have you seen `scipy.linalg.eig`? From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html#scipy.linalg.eig):

> Solve an ordinary or **generalized** eigenvalue problem of a square matrix.

This method have optional parameter `b`:

```
scipy.linalg.eig(a, b=None, ...
```

> ```
> b : (M, M) array_like, optional
> Right-hand side matrix in a generalized eigenvalue problem. 
>           Default is None, identity matrix is assumed.
> ```

Comment: The problem in OP is `Aw = xBw`.

Comment: so, what's the problem? `scipy.linalg.eig(a, b=None,...`: parameter b: _Right-hand side matrix in a generalized eigenvalue problem. Default is None, identity matrix is assumed._