# How to find the eigenvalues in Python with a matrix different to the identity matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I am trying to find the eigenvalues of a characteristic equation in Python, the problem is that in the equation |A-lambda I|=0, the matrix that multiplies lambda isn't the identity matrix, but I have to make clear that this matrix different to the identity matrix is a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is known as the generalized eigenvalue problem. An example solution with `numpy` is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752393/solve-generalized-eigenvalue-problem-in-numpy) question.