# In Python, how to solve generalized eigenvalue problem for matrices of differing dimensions?

Tags: python, matrix, covariance, eigenvalue

Is there a way to use `numpy.linalg.eigh()` or `scipy.linalg.eigh()` for solving the generalized eigenvalue problem ***A⋅x=λB⋅x*** when ***A*** and ***B*** do not have matching dimensions? E.g., for when ***A*** is a 4x4 matrix and ***B*** is a 5x5 matrix. Or is there another Python function that can handle that? If I try to use `eigh(A, B)` I get the following error for the scipy version:

```
    valueError: wrong b dimensions (6, 6), should be (4, 4)
```

and this error in the numpy version:

```
    'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'upper'
```

I found this answer [Solve Generalized Eigenvalue Problem in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752393/solve-generalized-eigenvalue-problem-in-numpy), which is fine for when both matrices are the same dimensions but I'm working on a multiple linear regression problem, trying to predict target values from input features, where ***A*** and ***B*** are symmetric matrices but of different dimensions to each other. I also tried this solution: https://guihongwan.github.io/2018/11/The-Generalized-Eigenvector-and-Eigenvalue-Problem/, but get an error for the same non-matching dimensions reason.

Background: I'm trying to use a set of input features, ***X ∈ R<sup>n×d</sup>***, where ***n*** is the number of observations and ***d*** is the number of input features, and a corresponding set of output values, ***Y ∈ R<sup>n×p</sup>*** where ***p*** is the number of output dimensions, to map ***X*** to ***Y*** so as to try to predict new ***Y_hat*** output. 
 As a mini example with dummy numbers, say ***X*** is a 5 x 4 input matrix of 5 observations and 4 features and ***Y*** is a 5 x 2 target matrix of 5 observations and 2 output values:

```
    X = [[1,2,3,4],
         [5,6,7,8],
         [4,3,2,1],
         [8,7,6,5],
         [9,6,4,2]]

    Y = [[8,7],
         [6,5],
         [4,3],
         [2,1],
         [1,9]]
```

I calculate the covariance matrix for the input ***X***:

```
    A = np.cov(X, rowvar=False)    # A = 4x4 matrix
```

Then I calculate the covariance matrix for the input and output:

```
    Cxy = np.hstack((X, Y))
    B = np.cov(Cxy, rowvar=False)    # B = 6x6 matrix
```

I then try to use ***A*** and ***B*** to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using `eigh()` but that's where I get stuck. Can anyone offer a solution please or spot where I've gone wrong?