# Dominant generalized eigenvector of a matrix pencil in Python

Tags: python

Given a matrix pencil (A,B) where A and B are NxN, how can I obtain the dominant generalized eigenvector in Python. I have seen this method scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh() in one of the answers but I think it can only work when given a matrix A but not for a matrix pencil?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Can you paste your code and tell us the problem your are facing.

Comment: have You tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752393/solve-generalized-eigenvalue-problem-in-numpy)